# Need to set a variable to a specific range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I have a page where I have to detect a div and upon clicking on that div, I need to change  the url of the page. The div ids are taken from an XML file in a tag called . Ids are range of numbers between 1 to 999, and the div which will be clicked has the following structure:

```
<div id="1">
```

I also have the URL change function which is:

```
$('yyy').live('click',function(){window.location = 'list.html?' + xxx + '';});
```

where  `var yyy = "#" + xxx;`  so that it adds the hash to the id variable making it possible for use in jquery function.

My problem is I need to define `xxx` as a number range between 1 to 999, I also have tried to set xxx to any of the id tags in my XML file by doing

```
var xxx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID");
```

but no luck so far.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give all the divs the same class?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand but the xxx variable should be equal to the id of the clicked element ? If so, you have access to the click event, and thus to the even.target

```
$('yyy').live('click',function(event){window.location = 'list.html?' + $(event.target).attr('id') + '';});
```

Comment: I think I provided alot of information... my main aim is to set xxx to be equal to any number between 1 to 999. then any id on the page which is taken from the XMl file (i.e div id="1") will be considered as div id="xxx" because somehow xxx is set to be some number between 1 to 999, right? and then I can use the yyy which will add a # to the xxx and use it in jquery code.

Comment: var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11) this generates random number from range 0-10. If you want a random number from 1-999 it would look something like this var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1

Comment: Thanks pkurek, but somehow the math random is not doing what I want. Lets stick to the first code you posted. I explain my exact scenario and lets see if we get anywhere! :) I have a page which loads 4 divs that include data pulled from an XML file. The ids of these divs come from the XML file. Now I need every time any of these divs are clicked, 1. The div id be detected and 2.  a function changes the url and adds the div id to the end of the url.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: So @DaveHomer everytime one of this four divs is clicked you need to fire up a function that detects the clicked div ID and then appends it (or changes the current ID in the url if a div was clicked before ) to the current url right ?

Comment: if so `$("FOUR DIV SELECTOR").live('click', function(event) {window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '#' + $(event.target).attr('id')})`

Comment: and if the divs arent added to the DOM dynamically you don't have to use $.live you can use just $.click() and if they are added dynamically its better to use $.delegate() insted of live() :) Hope it helped you

Comment: It did but how would I di this part? "$("FOUR DIV SELECTOR")" ? I need to say if Any div is clicked... how do I say that? I understand the second part which says get the clicked div id but I dont undrestand the first part!

Comment: oh :) so maybe add them a class value like `<div class='watch_if_clicked'> </div>` and then `$(".watch_if_clicked").live()`. You are using jQuery selectors here if you are new to jQuery it would be good to read some basic tutorials about it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14984/discussion-between-pkurek-and-dave-homer)

Answer (score 0):

Well Finally by the help of pkurek and some reading I managed to do it by the following code:

```
$('.all the divs on the page class').live('click', function() {window.location = 'list.html?' +  $(this).attr('id') + '';});
```

Which this will automatically detect the clicked div! :)